# What is a word to describe physically painful loneliness?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the sensation of emptiness, an emptiness endured for so long that it has evolved into physical pain.: Like you cannot breathe but at the same time feel unable to move or speak or do something you once loved.

Comment: Why would 'painful' not fir the bill all by itself?

Comment: I thought *despondent*, but I like vocabulary.com for connotational discussion, and they suggest *heartsick*.

Comment: Do you think there must always be a single word for every idea that incorporates a plurality of qualities?